# Submit form from another page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I have a problem when I try to submit a form from another page, which is loaded in a DOM element. The stated form element has following attributes and looks like this:

```
<form id="thisForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="some.php" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<table>
<tbody>

<tr>
<th><b>Title 1</b></th>
<td><select name="name1" id="id1"><option value="1">Selection 1</option><option value="2">Selection 2</option></select></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th><b>Title 2</b></th>
<td><textarea name="name2" id="id2"></textarea></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th><b>Title 3</b></th>
<td><select name="name3" id="id3"><option value="11">Selection 11</option><option value="12">Selection 12</option></select></td></tr>
<tr>

<td><input type="submit" name="__saveForm" value="Save"></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

And following the JS code, sorry for bad conventions:

```
var formwrap = document.createElement("div");
var formform = document.createElement("form");

$.get("some.php", null, function(html) {
    var htmlstring = html;
    formwrap.innerHTML= htmlstring;
    formform = formwrap.querySelector("#thisForm");

    document.body.appendChild(formform); // I need to append the form somewhere to the current page, or I get this error in chrome: "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected"

    formform.querySelector("#id1").value = '2';     // Set a value in form
    formform.querySelector("#id3").value = '12';    // Set a value in form

    formform.submit();

    }, "text");
```

When the code executes, I get redirected to the page where the form is included (some.php), but the form is not actually submitted. Also the selections I made via code are not present here.

Is there a way to submit this form without having the respective page (some.php) opened in the browser?

Modyfing the source code of the form element is unfortunately not an option, I can only change the javascript part.

Thank you for the help

Comment: Do you see the correctly generated form on the target page using devtools?  I don't follow your code, but is `formform` supposed to be defined 2x?

Comment: Yes, if i comment the submit() method out I can see the form in the source code of the target page correctly appended (I can also see the form visually). No, only the latter definition is relevant, my mistake.

Comment: A common problem when doing this kind of thing in jQuery is that selectors will only match elements that exist at page load; dynamically added elements won't match.  You are using (mostly) plain JS, which I'm less familiar with, but maybe that is happening?  Will `querySelector` match an element added after page load? Have you done some basic debugging, eg `console.dir(formform)`, etc, check that your selectors are actually working?

Comment: The querySelector works fine, I mean this must work since im using it on the objects created in the previous lines. I also just verified with `console.dir(formform)` and everything looks fine. Also the values I set via querySelector are chosen correctly.

I think the problem lies in the usage of the `submit()` method. Can it work like this when the form is dynamically loaded from another page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it.

I checked in Chrome Network Debug that the HTTP POST was sent out, but some parameters were missing compared to when i submit the form manually. I was able to add these via JS.

Comment: Great that you solved it. If you want to make this q/a actually useful for future visitors with similar problems, please describe your fix - `I was able to add these via JS` does not tell us anything, and the code in your question already does that.